# What does "inline" mean in the context of dbghelp.h?

Tags: winapi, dbghelp

The documentation for [`SymEnumSymbolsEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/windows/desktop/api/dbghelp/nf-dbghelp-symenumsymbolsex) reads:

```
SYMENUM_OPTIONS_DEFAULT 1     Use the default options.
SYMENUM_OPTIONS_INLINE 2      Enumerate inline symbols.
```

What are "inline symbols"? What do `SymFromInlineContext` and the other inline procedures do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know about [inline function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/inline-functions-cpp?view=vs-2017):
The function code is expanded at the point of the call at compile time which will save the overhead of a function call. So it doesn't look like a "real function call", Similar to macros function. However, different with macros function, it also has a symbol link.

Comment: OK I thought so but it doesn't talk about that on any of those documentation pages. Thanks.